# Distancia entre punto y segmento

Tags: python

Quiero calcular la distancia entre un punto y un segmento, el problema es que solo consigo calcular la distancia entre un punto y una linea (infinita, no acotada por dos puntos).

He usado esto:

```
d = norm(np.cross(p2-p1, p1-p3))/norm(p2-p1)
```

y funciona bien, pero eso, es la distancia entre la linea que une p1 y p2, con respecto al punto p3, pero yo quiero medir la distancia entre p3 y el segmento acotado por p1 y p2.

Alguna idea?

Comment: hahaha lo sacaste de [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39840218/3045491) ? Miraste [este](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1501725/3045491)? tiene considerablemente muchos mas puntos (327 veces más)

Comment: Hola, no lo habia visto, sabrias como pasarlo a python? Gracias

Comment: ah vaya, fallo mio, pensaba que también estaba en python, no lo vi perdona

Comment: @lois6b no es fallo tuyo, si que existe una respuesta para Python pero en la [tercera respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2233538/7131499) no en la aceptada :) (con el orden actual). Creo que funciona correctamente aunque no usa NumPy para los calculos ni la representación de los puntos.

Comment: Culpa mia, no vi que estaba resuelto en python. Aun asi al final encontré este [ejemplo](http://www.fundza.com/vectors/point2line/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existen varias formas de enfocar el problema, voy a intentar explicar una de ellas. Para no perdernos entre tanto punto voy a cambiar la nomenclatura que tu usas, los puntos que determinan el segmento serán llamados A y B, al segmento lo llamaremos A̅B̅, a la recta que pasa por A y B la llamaremos AB y al punto al que queremos calcular la distancia lo llamaremos P. Si desgranamos el problema básicamente hay cuatro posibilidades:

- El punto sea uno de los puntos que forman los extremos del segmento, es decir que `A==P` o `B==P`. La distancia es 0.
- Que sea posible hacer una proyección ortogonal de P sobre A̅B̅. En este caso equivale a calcular la distancia de P a la recta AB.
- Que no sea posible calcular la proyección ortogonal de P  sobre A̅B̅, es decir, la proyección ortogonal de P sobre AB está fuera de A̅B̅. En este caso hay dos posibilidades:

  - La proyección ortogonal de P sobre AB esté más cercana a A. La distancia será la distancia entre A y P.
  - La proyección ortogonal de P sobre AB esté más cercana a B. La distancia será la distancia entre B y P.

El problema se reduce a saber si el punto tiene o no proyección ortogonal sobre el segmento y si no la tiene ver a que extremo está más cercano. Podemos calcular el punto resultado de la proyección ortogonal sobre la recta y ver donde está con respecto al segmento. Otra posibilidad es imaginarnos un triángulo con vértices A, B y P:

- Si el punto no tiene proyección ortogonal sobre el segmento y está mas cercano a A entonces el angulo formado entre A̅B̅ y A̅P̅ será mayor de 90 grados.
- Si el punto no tiene proyección ortogonal sobre el segmento y está mas cercano a B entonces el angulo formado entre A̅B̅ y B̅P̅ será mayor de 90 grados.
- Si ninguno de los dos ángulos es mayor de 90 grados significa que si que existe proyección ortogonal del punto sobre el segmento.

Esta sería una posible implementación del rollo anterior XD:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

def distancia(A, B, P):
    #Comprobamos que el punto no corresponda a los extremos del segmento.
    if all(A==P) or all(B==P):
        return 0

    #Calculamos el angulo entre AB y AP, si es mayor de 90 grados retornamos la distancia enre A y P
    elif np.arccos(np.dot((P-A)/norm(P-A), (B-A)/norm(B-A))) > np.pi/2:
        return norm(P-A)

    #Calculamos el angulo entre AB y BP, si es mayor de 90 grados retornamos la distancia enre B y P.
    elif np.arccos(np.dot((P-B)/norm(P-B), (A-B)/norm(A-B))) > np.pi/2:
        return norm(P-B)

    #Como ambos angulos son menores o iguales a 90º sabemos que podemos hacer una proyección ortogonal del punto.
    return norm(np.cross(B-A, A-P))/norm(B-A)


A = np.array((5,3))
B = np.array((2,1))
P = np.array((1,2))
print(distancia(A, B, P))
```

Los puntos se le pasan a la función dentro de un array de NumPy: `numpy.array((x, y))`.